# Windows Server 2008R2 / Active Directory - firewall blocks inbound NTP via UDP?

Tags: active-directory

Got a head scratcher here.  Installed the OS, and configured for Active Directory role.  Works just fine.  I noticed that port 123/UDP (NTP) seems to be blocked for another host that is joined to the domain.  Looking at the windows firewall rules, I see there is one that says "Active Directory Domain Controller - W32Time (NTP-UDP-In) that is enabled with Action=Allow, yet the host is unable to do so.  If I manually add a rule that explictly allows 123/UDP inbound, suddenly the other host can get in.  The only difference I can see in the two rules, is that the AD one specifies svchost.exe.  Note that the AD rules were all created automatically when I installed the AD role.  I'm happy to leave this explicit rule in, but I'd love to know why the AD-created rule doesn't seem to work.  Thanks!

Comment: Which Windows Firewall profile is active on the affected member?

Comment: Pretty sure the domain one.  And just to be safe, the explicit firewall rule also said domain only (e.g. no private or public).